# Delayed unique queued mailable still being put in the queue

Tags: laravel

I have a Redis queue managed by Horizon. I'm trying to delay a mailable from sending for 15 minutes, while also preventing any future mail jobs from being added to the queue until after the 15 minutes has passed. I'm using the `ShouldBeUnique` interface along with the `WithoutOverlapping` middleware, but more mail jobs are added to the queue (under "Pending Jobs" in Horizon) as many times that I queue it to send.

I have a mail class setup as follows:

```php
namespace App\Mail;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\Middleware\WithoutOverlapping;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MyMailable extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels, InteractsWithQueue;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct(protected User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    public int $uniqueFor = 900; // 15 minutes

    public function uniqueId(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->user->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            to: 'email@example.com',
            subject: 'Subject',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            markdown: 'mail.view',
            with: []
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
     */
    public function attachments(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function middleware(): array
    {
        return [
            (new WithoutOverlapping($this->user->id))
                ->dontRelease(),
        ];
    }
}
```

I send the mail by calling `Mail::send()`:

```php
Mail::send(
    (new MyMailable($user))
        ->delay(now()->addMinutes(15))
);
```

The mail is delayed 15 minutes, however there are other jobs added to the queue within my `$uniqueFor` limit. Is there a way I can the same mailable from being added to the queue?